# How to Create Dictionary from set of strings Python

Tags: python

I have an output somewhat of the form below. How do I turn it into a dictionary or pandas indexed 2D array?

```
'{"key1":true,"key2":[1,1,1],"key3":[[["name1",0],["name2",0]],[[1,0][1,0][1,0]]}'
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: That's JSON. Use `json.loads()` to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are missing commas in the last value.

```
[[1,0][1,0][1,0]]]}'
```

This should be:

```
[[1,0],[1,0],[1,0]]]}'
```

When fixed, you get:

```
>>> import json
>>> foo = '{"key1":true,"key2":[1,1,1],"key3":[[["name1",0],["name2",0]],[[1,0],[1,0],[1,0]]]}'
>>> json.loads(foo)
{u'key3': [[[u'name1', 0], [u'name2', 0]], [[1, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0]]], u'key2': [1, 1, 1], u'key1': True}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import ast
s = '{"key1":true,"key2":[1,1,1],"key3":[[["name1",0],["name2",0]],[[1,0],[1,0],[1,0]]}'
final_data = ast.literal_eval(s)
```